# Inject value by custom annotation when creating scoped bean

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm trying to inject value by custom annotation, which is similar to `@Value` annotation.

Below is an example using `@Value` annotation.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    fun myBean(@Value("\${my.properties.foo}") foo: String) { ... }
}
```

Whenever I request `myBean`, argument for `foo` would be required from application's properties(e.g. application.yml), right?

Instead of `@Value`, I wanna use custom annotation named `@MyAnnotation`, like below.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    fun myBean(@MyAnnotation foo: String) { ... }
}
```

and let's say the argument for `foo` would be retrieved from `MyObject`.
(Obviously the retrieval from `MyObject` is an example)

```kotlin
object MyObject {
    var x = 1 // mutable
}
```

In this case, how can I achieve this ? I've searched about 'BeanPostProcessor', but couldn't sure that it is for this case.(especially with bean from `@Configuration`, not `@Component`)